# Calculate MAX and MIN latitude and longitude with variable distance from a location

Tags: sql, math, latitude-longitude, scalar

I need to compute a maximum and minimum latitude and longitude, to be able to filter through a huge set a data more easily before computing distance between two points.
However, I'm not finding anything out there where the distance is variable, so I came up with the following since I figured I could perhaps compute these in steps:

```
DECLARE @area int = (69 * FLOOR(@maxDist/69) + 1)
DECLARE @lonMin float = @originLon - @maxDist/abs(cos(radians(@originLat)) * @area);
DECLARE @lonMax float = @originLon + @maxDist/abs(cos(radians(@originLat)) * @area);
DECLARE @latMin float = @originLat - (@maxDist/@area);
DECLARE @latMax float = @originLat + (@maxDist/@area);
```

When I try to apply the values I get here with my where statement, the search fails when above a single degree difference.

```
WHERE
    (endPoint.Longitude >= @lonMin and endPoint.Longitude <= @lonMax)
    and
    (endPoint.Latitude >= @latMin and endPoint.Longitude <= @latMax)
```

My best guess is that my lonMin and lonMax are wrong, but I'm not sure where I've broken it.  I'm fairly certain I'm using the correct formulas - the others I've viewed so far are the same - so is the issue my computed `@area` or something else?
(I'm working with Miles and example inputs like 33.631701,
-111.877582)

Comment: You should look into the GIS function or extension for whatever database you are using.

Comment: The geography capabilities of my DB are good, I know what they are and how to use them, but a consequence of using them is a huge loss in speed.  
Because it is significantly larger and more costly than what I'm doing, I'd rather avoid it, even at the loss of some accuracy (which isn't extraordinarily important in my use-case)

Comment: @Nol I've worked out that 69 is the approximate distance in miles of a one-degree trip along the equator.. However I'm at a loss to guess what `area` is supposed to be. You wrote: "I'm fairly certain I'm using the correct formulas - the others I've viewed so far are the same" -- URL(s) please. It appears to have problems when distance is e.g. 67.5, 68.0,68.5 miles.

Comment: You gave me a good idea when you mentioned that 69 was approx one-degree.  I tried going back to the original formulas where I didn't try to add in my step-function of `area` and I figured out I was plugging in my values entirely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had the right formulas for what I needed to do, but I was using them wrong.  I didn't realize that I was plugging in the number of degrees in miles (`@area`) I wanted to search where I should have been just putting the the baseline of 1 degree.

Changing the values I put in to gives the desired expansion of 1-degree-at-a-time area filtering - so searching for something within 40mi of the the origin point will filter out all DB results that are not within 69mi of the origin, and searching for 94mi away will filter out those not within 138mi, etc.

I realize `@degree` does not have to be declared in this scenario, but I found doing so clarified my issue for me.

```
DECLARE @degree int = 69
DECLARE @area int = @degree * (FLOOR(@maxDist/@degree) + 1);
DECLARE @lonMin float = @originLon - @area/(abs(cos(radians(@originLat)) * @degree));
DECLARE @lonMax float = @originLon + @area/(abs(cos(radians(@originLat)) * @degree));
DECLARE @latMin float = @originLat - (@area/@degree);
DECLARE @latMax float = @originLat + (@area/@degree);
```